# Simple search in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem with a simple browser in my application.
I have already looked for solutions but still displays the following error:
param is missing or the value is empty: expense.

Please help.
Index:

```
<%= form_tag expenses_path :method => 'get' do %>
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
<%= submit_tag "Search" , name: nil %>
```

Controller:

class ExpensesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_expense, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

```
# GET /expense  expense
# GET /expense.json
def index
  @expenses = Expense.search(params[:search])
end

# GET /expense/1
# GET /expense/1.json
def show
end

# GET /expense/new
def new
  @expense = Expense.new
end

# GET /expense/1/edit
def edit
end

# POST /expense
# POST /expense.json
def create
  @expense = Expense.new(expense_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @expense.save
      format.html { redirect_to @expense, notice: 'zostały zapisane.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @expense }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @expense.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# PATCH/PUT /expense/1
# PATCH/PUT /expense/1.json
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @expense.update(expense_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @expense, notice: 'expense was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @expense }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @expense.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# DELETE /expense/1
# DELETE /expense/1.json
def destroy
  @expense.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @expense, notice: 'Zakupy zostały usunięte.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_expense
    @expense = Expense.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
 def expense_params
    params.require(:expense).permit(:date, :price, :category, :where)
 end
```

Expense.rb:

```
class Expense < ApplicationRecord
def self.search(search)
    if search
        where (['where LIKE ?',"%#{search}%"])
    else
        all
    end
end
```

Comment: whats your index method????

Comment: As @AbhishekAravindan has said, please provide the full controller code

Comment: As a suggestion, it's a bad idea to name a model attribute / database column `where` because it will conflict with the Rails method of the same name.

Comment: I added all controller

Answer (score 1):

permit the search in your params

```
 def expense_params
   params.require(:expense).permit(:date, :price, :category, :where, :search)
 end
```

please correct the form_tag syntax

```
<%= form_tag(expenses_path,method: :get) do %>
 <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
 <%= submit_tag "Search" , name: nil %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The index method does not call `expense_params`, and that form will not nest the `:search` param under `params[:expense]`

Comment: for rails version above 5, we have to do so, https://rubyplus.com/articles/3381-Simple-Search-Form-in-Rails-5 refer this, this only work and this too https://medium.com/@yassimortensen/simple-search-form-in-rails-8483739e4042

Comment: Parameters only need to be permitted if they are being used to create or update an ActiveRecord object, e.g. `Expense.create(params[:expense])` would throw an 'Unpermitted Parameters' error, but `Expense.find(params[:id])` would not.

Comment: please refer above articles and come to a conclusion,

Comment: Thank you for your help. @Abhishek Aravindan your solution works ;)

Comment: @green if this solution works for you please accept as answer give a upvote, welcome!

Comment: @AbhishekAravindan from the Rails documentation: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html
"Allows you to choose which attributes should be *whitelisted for mass updating*"

Answer (score 0):

The error message you report is most likely coming from your `expense_params` method:

`params.require(:expense)` means you expect the parameters to be of the form `params[:expense][:date]`, `params[:expense][:price]`, etc.

My best guess is that your form is not actually submitting a GET request and so it's going to the `create` method rather than the index method.

I think this may be occurring because you are missing a comma between `expenses_path` and `:method => 'get'` in your `form_tag`. It should be:

```rb
<%= form_tag expenses_path, :method => 'get' do %>
```

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it doesn't need to send an expense param because the index method doesn't call `expense_params`

Comment: Thank you for your help. @DaveMongoose your solution works but there is a problem adding more data to the database.